# How to loop through a list of strings based on user input

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to code a program in Python 3.9 that will tell a student how many more semesters they will need in order to complete their course of study, based on their current class level (note: at our school we refer to semesters as "sessions"). The program asks a student to input their current semester, and their current level.
I was able to get the program to generate the correct output if a student is starting in the very first session and lowest class level , but if the student is starting from a later session and/or a higher level, an error occurs because the program runs out of levels.

Here is the relevant code:

```
sessions = ['Session 3, 2021','Session 4, 2021','Session 5, 2021','Session 6, 2021','Session 1, 2022','Session 2, 2022']

user_session = input('what session is this?: ')

if user_session == "1":
   current_session = sessions[0]
elif user_session == "2":
    current_session = sessions[1]
#etc for remaining sessions

levels = ['foundation','int a','int b','int c','advanced a','advanced b']

user_level = input('what is your starting level?: ')

if user_level == "1":
    current_level = levels[0]
elif user_level == "2":
    current_level = levels[1]
#etc for remaining sessions 

while True:
current_level <= levels[5] 
#I want the code to stop running once a student completes the highest level
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session)]), ": ",(levels[levels.index(current_level)]))
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 1]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 1]))
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 2]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 2]))
#etc for remaining print calls

    break 
#necessary or else the program keeps looping since my 'current_level <= levels[5]' doesn't seem to be doing anything
```

If the student starts at the first session and bottom level, the correct output is generated:

```
what session is this?: 1
what is your starting level?: 1
Session 3, 2021 :  foundation
Session 4, 2021 :  int a
Session 5, 2021 :  int b
Session 6, 2021 :  int c
Session 1, 2022 :  advanced a
Session 2, 2022 :  advanced b
```

But, if the student starts at a later session or higher level, an error results:

```
Ex:

what session is this?: 2
what is your starting level?: 2
Session 4, 2021 :  int a #note: here 'int' is a string abbreviation for 'intermediate level'
Session 5, 2021 :  int b
Session 6, 2021 :  int c
Session 1, 2022 :  advanced a
Session 2, 2022 :  advanced b

#So far the output is all correct, but following error message appears after the last line:

print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 5]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 5]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I get the loop to quit so that this IndexError doesn't occur? Thanks, and apologies for inelegant code, I am newbie to Python and programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider. You don't have any real logic to handle stopping conditions. You cannot just hard-code a certain number of levels in a loop like that, it isn't manageable. The reason you have the out-of-bounds is because you literally are stepping out of bounds of the data. I suggest several things:

1. If you can find time, setup an IDE like Visual Studio Code, so that you can step through and watch variables change with each step; much more insightful.
2. To your question, do a version of your program *without levels*, just *sessions only*, and get that logic working correctly. Then add in the levels. Consider that right now you have the same number of sessions as levels, I think, but perhaps that's not always the case.
3. Replace the `if user_session == "1"` blocks with something like this:

   `current_session = ord(user_session) - ord('0') - 1`
   This means you have an offset into your sessions list. In Python, lists are roughly equivalent to arrays in other languages. Anyway, see my next point.
4. Your while loop needs a counting variable, call it `session_offset`. Inside the while loop, you will increment the session_offset variable by 1. The while loop will check against the maximum number of elements in your sessions list, which you can get with `len(sessions)`. So, it runs *while* the `session_offset` is less than the number of possible sessions. Then a simpler way to print the session will be something like this:

   ```
   print(sessions[current_session + session_offset])
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Hey there your code is right but it needs to be modified a little bit.
you could put

```
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
    break
```

by typing it between each one like this:

```
while True:
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break
    #I want the code to stop running once a student completes the highest level
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session)]), ": ",(levels[levels.index(current_level)]))
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break    
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 1]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 1]))
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break    
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 2]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 2]))
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 3]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 3])) 
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break      
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 4]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 4]))
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break          
    print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 5]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 5])) 
    if current_level <= levels[5] :
        break
```

and your code must be like this

```
sessions = ['Session 3, 2021','Session 4, 2021','Session 5, 2021','Session 6, 2021','Session 1, 2022','Session 2, 2022']

user_session = input('what session is this?: ')

if user_session == "1":
   current_session = sessions[0]
elif user_session == "2":
    current_session = sessions[1]
#etc for remaining sessions

levels = ['foundation','int a','int b','int c','advanced a','advanced b']

user_level = input('what is your starting level?: ')

if user_level == "1":
    current_level = levels[0]
elif user_level == "2":
    current_level = levels[1]
#etc for remaining sessions 

while True:
    try:
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break
        #I want the code to stop running once a student completes the highest level
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session)]), ": ",(levels[levels.index(current_level)]))
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break    
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 1]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 1]))
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break    
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 2]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 2]))
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 3]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 3])) 
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break      
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 4]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 4]))
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break          
        print((sessions[sessions.index(current_session) + 5]), ": ", (levels[levels.index(current_level) + 5])) 
        if current_level <= levels[5] :
            break          
        #etc for remaining print calls

        break 
    except:
        IndexError
        break
```

if you type 1 and 1 your output will be :

```
    Session 3, 2021 :  foundation
Session 4, 2021 :  int a
Session 5, 2021 :  int b
Session 6, 2021 :  int c
Session 1, 2022 :  advanced a
Session 2, 2022 :  advanced b
```

and if you type 2 and 2 the output will be??

```
Session 4, 2021 :  int a
Session 5, 2021 :  int b
Session 6, 2021 :  int c
Session 1, 2022 :  advanced a
Session 2, 2022 :  advanced b
```

Comment: my code is edited now if that is what you mean??